# Is there a way to update state without Trigering a re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

I'm making an app where you can practice your math  I have a function that returns two random numbers on the render of the page and I pass down input to collect the user's answer in estate it has a change that runs the setusersAnswer() to the value entered in the input. but the problem is that every time I enter something it re-renders the entire question on every change made to the input component users answer.

here is the function in my  component :

```
 const Question = ({input}) => {
    
         const makeQuestion = () => {
            firstNumber = randomRange();
            secondNumber = randomRange();
        
            return <>{`${firstNumber} +${secondNumber}`}</>;
          };


          return (<>
    {makeQuestion()}
{input}
    </>)}
        export default Question;
```

in my app js, I have a text input:

app.js:

```
function App() {
      const [UserAnswer, setUserAnswer] = useState('')
const handleUserAnswer=(val)=>{
  setUserAnswer(val);

}

return(

    <Question input={<Input  handleUserAnswer={handleUserAnswer}/>} />

)}
```

my input component looks like this :

```
const Userinput = ({handleUserAnswer}) => {
 return (


 <Input onChange={handleUserAnswer}>
)}
```

now I cleaned up this code so there are only the basic parts here is a visual representation of what the issue is:

[image]

if I enter anything into the input it triggers a rerender and different The random number function runs again.

[image]

it triggers a re-render of the whole UI which I don't want. I want to store the user's answer without triggering a re-render.

Comment: try `makeQuestion` instead of `makeQuestion()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the question *in the title* - no. Setting state fundamentally will trigger a re-render; React's view is designed to flow directly from the state, so when the state changes, the view is supposed to change too.

As to the *body* of your question - it looks like a simple tweak that would get you what you want would be to create `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` only once, regardless of re-renders. Since they don't ever change for a given component, they could be either state or a ref.

```
const Question = ({ input }) => {
    const [numbers] = useState(() => [randomRange(), randomRange()]);
    return (<>
        {`${numbers[0]} +${numbers[1]}`}
        {input}
    </>)
}
export default Question;
```

There will still be re-renders, but now that the random numbers have only been generated once, the re-renders won't cause problems. (Don't be afraid of re-rendering. It's not often problematic.)

Comment: And `setNumbers([randomRange(), randomRange()])` would create new numbers when needed... with `const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState(() => [randomRange(), randomRange()]);`

Comment: Agreed. Rerenders aren't really that big of a deal unless there's an expensive computation that needs to be done, and React (generally) is pretty good about managing them.